# React syntax question for React.ComponentProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Just want to a question about React.ComponentProps itself.

Still learning the syntax, do you guys know the meaning of this code below

```
type Props = React.ComponentProps<typeof ComponmentA> & {
    someProp: string;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Found out. It's intersection type :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down.

First [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) -  typeof infers a type from a constant.

So for example

```
const foo = {
 a: "hello", 
 b: 999
}; 

type TypeofFoo = typeof foo; 

//type TypeofFoo = {
//    a: string;
//    b: number;
//}
```

So for typeof a React component:

```
const MyComponent = (props: {
    name: string
}) => {
    const {name} = props; 
    return <div>{name}</div>
}

type  TypeofMyComponent = typeof MyComponent; 
//type TypeofMyComponent = (props: {
//    name: string;
//}) => JSX.Element
```

We can see the the typeof a React component in this case is just a function with a particular signature and returns a JSX.Element.

Second `React.ComponentProps` - appears to just extract the props of a React component. So:

```
type ComponentPropsOfTypeofMyComponent = ComponentProps<TypeofMyComponent>; 
//type ComponentPropsOfTypeofMyComponent = {
//    name: string;
//}
```

Thirdly the `&` syntax is just creating a [type intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html)

So for example:

```
type A = {
   name: string; 
}

type B = {
    age: number; 
}

type C = A & B; 
// type C = {
//   name: string; 
//   age: number; 
// }
```

Long story short - what that code is doing is saying 'Hey whatever the shape of the props of ComponentA is - and add `{someProps: string;}` to it'.